# Group by time range in R

Tags: r, time, average, group

I have a dataset which gives a temparture value every 5 minutes for multiple days. The aim is to group 2 time ranges (7:30-10:00 and 11:30-14:00) under the names 'morning' and 'midday' and get the temp average of all the values within that range.
Now I have with time seen as characters:

```
 Time    Temp   
[1,] "13:05" "35.115"
[2,] "13:10" "33.953"
[3,] "13:15" "32.497"
[4,] "13:20" "31.574"
[5,] "13:25" "30.963"
```

..and so on.

My end product would look something like:

```
Time_range   Temp
[1,] Morning      22
[2,] Midday       31
```

Hope someone can help me out!

Answer (score 2):

Having time as character should not be an issue here:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Time_range = case_when(Time >= "7:30" & Time <= "10:00" ~ "morning",
                                  Time >= "11:30" & Time <= "14:00" ~ "midday")) %>%
  summarize(Average_temp = mean(Temp))
```

Comment: Is this the answer? Please mark it as the answer.